# Java web app не видит статические файлы. JS, CSS и т.д. Развертываю на Spring MVC

Tags: maven, spring, spring-mvc, java, tomcat

Я использую Spring mvc+maven+tomcat. Когда я пишу java web app проект в NetBeans, я его периодически запускаю кнопкой F6 (Run Project). То есть я не произвожу его явное развертывание на Томкате. Этим я хочу проверить только что внесённые изменения.  И это стало *бо-о-о-ольшой* ошибкой для меня. Это аукнулось.
Имеется вот такая структура папок-файлов:

[image]

В form.jsp вызываю свои файлы так:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/css1.css">
<script type="text/javascript" 
                src="/js/jquery-2.1.3.js">
</script>
```

И конечно же, в конфиге спринга прописал пути, ну чтобы спринг мог находить статические ресурсы:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/WEB-INF/css/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/WEB-INF/js/" />
```

**Суть проблемы:**
Когда я запускаю кнопкой F6 всё работает хорошо. Все JS, CSS подключаются как надо.
Но когда я делаю mvn package и выкидываю готовый war в папку webapps томката, он не находит эти статические файлы. Открывается только голая form.jsp безо всяких CSS, JS.
Что делать?

**Вторая проблема**: очень странно, что при запуске F6 путь URL в браузере не такой, как при запуске задеплоенного war. Если я запускаю F6  - путь такой `http://localhost:8080/spring-chat-test/`
 A если запускаю задеплоенный, то `http://localhost:8080/spring-chat-test-1.0/`

Comment: В мавене в build прописаны ресурсы? Они физически присутствуют в распакованном war?

Задеплоенный, предположу, берет версию из названия варника.

Comment: Распаковал .war - файлы CSS, JS есть. В мавене в build не прописывал. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html как понял отсюда - в build надо прописывать внешние ресурсы, а ресурсы webapp должны сами вкладываться, что и происходит

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это решилось использованием jstl:

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/css/css.css"/>">
```

Они добавляют контекст (путь) откуда установлено веб приложение.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте добавить контекст приложения в URL JS-скриптов и стилей.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/css/css1.css">
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/js/jquery-2.1.3.js">
</script>
```

По поводу второй проблемы. Скорее всего в NetBeans в настройках проекта явно прописан контекст /spring-chat-test, в то время как в томкате контекст == имени папки, в которую задеплоилось приложение (в вашем случае это spring-chat-test-1.0). Самое простое - настроить maven, чтобы тот собирал war с нужным именем. Например так:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <finalName>spring-chat-test</finalName>
  </build>

</project>
```