# Некорректное отображение страницы веб приложения на Java Spring

Tags: java, html, spring

Сверстал простую HTML форму с подключением CSS стилей, имеются набор изображений и все файлы лежат в одной паке. Если открывают HTML документ просто через браузер всё выглядит как надо. Но мне надо добавить некоторую логику для обрабтки форму, поэтому решил сделать всё приложение через Spring. Добавил все файлы связанные со страничкой в папку, поэтому в HTML коде указывал относительные пути картинок и расположение .CSS файла. При запуске приложения, открываю в браузере страницы, а на них нет ни картинок, ни стилей. Не понимаю тогда как надо всё организовывать
[image: структура Java проекта]

[image: так должна выглядеть страница]

[image: так она выглядит на самом деле]

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="description" content="ВКонтакте – универсальное средство для общения и поиска друзей и одноклассников, которым ежедневно пользуются десятки миллионов человек. Мы хотим, чтобы друзья, однокурсники, одноклассники, соседи и коллеги всегда оставались в контакте.">
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="176">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Jekyll v4.1.1">


  
    <title></title>

   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
   
    
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="fav_logo.ico" sizes="180x180">
<link rel="icon" href="fav_logo.ico" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
<link rel="icon" href="fav_logo.ico" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/docs/4.5/assets/img/favicons/manifest.json">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/docs/4.5/assets/img/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#563d7c">
<link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.5/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="/docs/4.5/assets/img/favicons/browserconfig.xml">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#563d7c">


    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body class="text-center">
   
    <form class="form-signin">

  <div class="PageBlock">
  <div class="form_item">
  <img class="mb-4" src="logo_vk.png" alt="" width="50" height="50">
  <h1 class="h5 topText"></b></h1>


  <input type="text" id="inputEmail" class="form-control bgcolor border" placeholder="Телефон или email" required autofocus>


  <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control bgcolor border" placeholder="Пароль" required>


  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-blue btn-block border" type="submit">Войти</button>

</div>
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему не получается подключить css и js к html странице в Spring MVC проекте? Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/894259/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-css-%d0%b8-js-%d0%ba-html-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%b2-spring-mvc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5-j)

Comment: Или https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/408808/java-web-app-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-js-css-%d0%b8-%d1%82-%d0%b4-%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b0-spring-mv и еще есть парочка подобных вопросов. Поищите тут по запросу `spring mvc css` или `spring mvc javascript`